# Why is there a difference between the running time of these two algorithms?

Tags: java, performance, prime-factoring

As a part of a larger problem, I had to find the sum of prime factors of an integer `n`. I wrote my own version, but my solution to the problem timed out. I looked online and found a *different* version of the same method, summing the prime factors of an integer, and when I changed nothing but that one method, the solution was fast enough. But I can't find any difference in the running time just based on looking at the code.

My (slower) version:

```
static int factors(int n) {
        int total = 0;
        while (n % 2 == 0) {
            total += 2;
            n /= 2;
        }
        int j = 3;
        while (n > 1) {
            while (n % j == 0) {
                total += j;
                n /= j;
            }
            j += 2;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

The (faster) version I found:

```
static int factors(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 2;
        while (true) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                n /= i;
                sum += i;
                if (isPrime(n)) {
                    sum += n;
                    break;
                }
                i = 1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

For the sake of brevity, I'm not including the `isPrime` method in the bottom one; it's just the basic brute force one looping to `sqrt(n)`, not even Sieve of Eratosthenes.

If anything, I would've thought my version would be faster, because it gets all the duplicates of a prime factor out of the way, and also doesn't require repeatedly testing if a number is prime.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **it depends on your input**.

I believe that on paper the complexity of the 2 algorithms is the same: `O(n log(n))` (assuming that `isPrime(n)` has a complexity of `O(log(n))` - and please if someone better than me at calculating Big O can confirm or deny it would be great), so they should be pretty much equivalent, but as you know this analysis requires the assumption of the worst case.

In practice:

E.g. imagine your number `n` is 3^1000, your method will divide it by 3 some 1000 times, the second method will divide it by 3, then 9, then 27, etc, cutting down the number of operations required.

In general I would assume that if in `n` there is the same factor multiple times your method will be slower.

Comment: Am I just horrendously misunderstanding the second algorithm? The way I see it, if the input was 3^1000, the second algorithm would first divide by three. And then `i` would get reset to `1`, so then after two loops, it would divide by `3` again. And this process would get repeated 1000 times.

Comment: It could be log(n) if the input value is even. If it is odd, the coplexity is (n). It really depends on input - in best case it is log(n), but in worst (n).

For example: 999 -> it is not divisible by two, so you'll need 499 iterations - it is n * 0,5. If you have an input equals to 499 you'll have 249 iterations which is also n * 0,5. That means O(n).

But for 1000 (and 500) it will be O(log(n)).

Comment: Summing up - the complexity of first algorithm is O(n). The second algorithm has a bit better complexity but it is really hard to calculate. And it is not so far from O(n).

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey I guess, the second algorithm works like you wrote and that's indeed really inefficient. But it can break out early, which makes it faster (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has an error. You are always adding `j += 2`. But prime factors are increasing by two only to 13. Next one is 17 (not 15).
The further you go - the average step between prime number is longer.
In your algorithm you're always stepping by two.

Here are prime factors to 1000:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181 191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229 233 239 241 251 257 263 269 271 277 281 283 293 307 311 313 317 331 337 347 349 353 359 367 373 379 383 389 397 401 409 419 421 431 433 439 443 449 457 461 463 467 479 487 491 499 503 509 521 523 541 547 557 563 569 571 577 587 593 599 601 607 613 617 619 631 641 643 647 653 659 661 673 677 683 691 701 709 719 727 733 739 743 751 757 761 769 773 787 797 809 811 821 823 827 829 839 853 857 859 863 877 881 883 887 907 911 919 929 937 941 947 953 967 971 977 983 991 997 1009
```

In your algorithm you'll have 500 numbers (step by two).

So if you've a big number - you'll have much more iterations than the second algorithm.

Comment: In the second algorithm, isn't `i` reset to 1 after dividing by a new prime factor? So wouldn't it have the same problem of number of iterations?

Comment: Yes, but after first iteration it grows to 2. Then 3, 4, ... I think the average step will be much larger in the second algorithm (in case you have `n` big enough). You can display number of steps to the screen and compare it.

Comment: You're right with that the average step gets bigger and bigger, but I wouldn't call it an error (an "inefficiency" sounds better). Anyway, I believe, there's a different reason why the second algorithm is faster (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

The second method profits from early break, while your method keeps iterating until `j` reaches `n`. For big `n`, this takes ages....

Use a condition like `while (n > 1 && n <= j * j)`, so you can break out at about `sqrt(n)` instead of `n` (I mean the original `n` given as parameter, rather than the current value).

When you exit due to the second part of the condition, don't forget that with `n > 1` is the last factor.